# Проблема с Slick Slider: скрипт задает огромную ширину слайдам

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

В мобильной версии сайта элемент перестраивается в слайдер:

```js
$('.implants-install__list').slick({
  responsive: [{
   breakpoint: 1199,
   settings: {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    fade: true,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow: '<div class="slide-arrow slide-next slide-arrow--accent"><svg><use xlink:href="'+$(document.body).attr("data-template-path")+'images/sprites.svg#arrow"></use></svg></div>',
    prevArrow: '<div class="slide-arrow slide-prev slide-arrow--accent"><svg><use xlink:href="'+$(document.body).attr("data-template-path")+'images/sprites.svg#arrow"></use></svg></div>',
    infinite: true,
    // dots: true,
    customPaging: function (slider, i) {
     var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
     return '<a>' + i + '</a>';
    }
   }
  }, ]
 });
```

Ранее все было в порядке, скрипты не менялись, однако теперь наблюдается проблема: скрипт считает огромную ширину для item'ов слайдера и не добавляет классы к кнопкам переключения: http://prntscr.com/mkfano

В результате слайдер просто не отображается на странице: http://prntscr.com/mkfb7f

При этом все остальные слайдеры на сайте инициализируются точно также и работают корректно. Сталкивались с такой проблемой? Как ее можно решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После нескольких дней мучений выявила, что проблема была в том, что у блока .implants-install__list (то есть того, к которому применялся Slick) задано CSS-свойство display: flex; 
Изменение на display: block; решает проблему.